# Controls.Add(interface)

Tags: .net, controls, interface

I have an interface that is implemented in a customcontrol:

```
public interface IArrow{...}
pulblic class Arrow1:UserControl, IArrow{....}
pulblic class Arrow2:UserControl, IArrow{....}
```

Then i have my form that shows the arrows doing:

```
Arrow1 arr1=new Arrow1();
Arrow2 arr2=new Arrow1();
this.Controls.Add(arr1);
this.Controls.Add(arr2);
```

But I want to be able to do this:

```
IArrow arr1=new Arrow1();
IArrow arr2=new Arrow1();
this.Controls.Add(arr1);
```

The problem is that I need to cast to add to controls:

```
this.Controls.Add((Arrow1)arr1);
```

So my question is what interface my interface has to implement to be able to add into controls?
So my IArrow would be:

```
public interface IArrow:InterfaceToAddToControls {...}
```

(this is a summary not the full code as you can imagine)

Answer (score 2):

The argument of the Control.ControlCollection.Add() method must be of type Control.  That's not an interface type.  Your control is already derived from Control, no cast is needed.  You'll just need a separate local variable, no way around that:

```
  var ctl = new Arrow1();
  this.Controls.Add(ctl);
  IArrow arr1 = ctl;
```

Or a little helper method:

```
private IArrow AddArrow(Control ctl) {
  this.Controls.Add(ctl);
  return ctl as IArrow;
}
...
  IArrow arr1 = AddArrow(new Arrow1());
```